# Close window with middle mouse button in Expose

Tags: mission-control, expose

How can I configure Expose to enable closing of Windows with the middle mouse button, like it is possible in Compiz/Scale Plugin on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**BetterTouchTool**](https://www.boastr.net).

1. Add a new button in Global for Normal Mice.
2. Set Middle Mouse Button.
3. Choose Predefined Action: ‘Close Window Below Cursor (Works in Mission Control)’.

[image: BetterTouchTool window]

Comment: I'm sorry, I've recently tried this solution and, unfortunatelly for me, what it does is simply close the window on a mouse middle click independently from being or not in the Expose's Mission Control view. In example: when I middle click on a link in Chrome, it closes the whole window instead of opening the link in a new tab. Seems that the "Works in Mission Control" label is not that true... :(